# Double comma when using APS citation style in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing

I want to use the [biblatex-phys](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-phys?lang=en) citation style in my presentation. More specific, I use some options of this package described [here](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-phys/blob/master/biblatex-phys.tex) to specify (more or less) the APS standard (in my case: removing the title, and show only the first page in the paper. For the citation style I have chosen author year, but that is not important.

My problem now: In the bibliography in the end, as well as when using `\footfullcite`, there are two commata after the authors. I suspect, the second one is from the suppressed title, since there is no extra comma when the title is not suppressed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=phys,
    articletitle=false,
    pageranges=false,
    citestyle=authoryear
    ]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{ICD.bib}
@article{santra_non-hermitian_2002,
    title = {Non-Hermitian electronic theory and applications to clusters},
    volume = {368},
    issn = {0370-1573},
    url =     {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157302001436},
    doi = {10.1016/S0370-1573(02)00143-6},
    abstract = {Electronically excited cations, generated by inner-valence ionization of small molecules, relax in general by dissociation and photon emission. Autoionization is forbidden for energetic reasons. The situation changes fundamentally in an inner-valence ionized cluster, which releases its excess energy by emitting an electron. This novel process, referred to as Intermolecular Coulombic Decay, is characterized by an efficient energy transfer between monomers in the cluster. The decay is ultrafast, taking place on a femtosecond time scale. Theoretical tools are developed to predict the properties, in particular lifetimes, of molecular systems undergoing electronic decay. These methods are applied to study the relaxation of inner-valence holes in clusters. In order to enable a treatment of the scattering and the many-particle problem with standard electronic correlation methods for bound states, a complex absorbing potential is added to the Hamiltonian. Conceptual as well as practical aspects of this procedure are discussed in detail.},
    pages = {1--117},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Physics Reports},
    shortjournal = {Physics Reports},
    author = {Santra, Robin and Cederbaum, Lorenz S.},
    urldate = {2017-09-05},
    date = {2002-09-01},
    keywords = {Ab initio calculations, Clusters, Resonance states, Valence ionization, {ToDo}, {HF}},
    file = {ScienceDirect Full Text PDF:/home/severin/Dokumente/Uni/Zotero/storage/MDI3XT7E/Santra und Cederbaum - 2002 - Non-Hermitian electronic theory and applications t.pdf:application/pdf;ScienceDirect Snapshot:/home/severin/Dokumente/Uni/Zotero/storage/Z38JXCVE/S0370157302001436.html:text/html}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{ICD}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
            cite: \cite{santra_non-hermitian_2002}\\
            autocite: \autocite{santra_non-hermitian_2002}\\
            footfullcite: \footfullcite{santra_non-hermitian_2002}

        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

what results in:[image]

Note, that this seams to be a specific problem of the `beamer` class: When using `\documentclass{article}` the same preamble with

```
\begin{document}
        \vspace*{15cm} % just for a more compact screenshot
        cite: \cite{santra_non-hermitian_2002}\\
        autocite: \autocite{santra_non-hermitian_2002}\\
        footfullcite: \footfullcite{santra_non-hermitian_2002}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields: [image]

Where the double comma is not shown.
I would really appreciate it, if someone could explain to me why this happens, and how I can get rid of it.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comments and the Answer: on my other machine with the current versions everything is fine. Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce your issues from your MWE. Most likely you don't use up to date packages. Please include a `\listfiles` in your preamble and post the resulting section from your log-file here.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue either. I think I remember one or two `beamer` bugs about this that were fixed a while ago (https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/348, https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/331, https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/pull/389). What version of `beamer` do you use? I'm using `beamer` 3.50 from 2018-02-20.

Comment: thaks!. I use
 eamer.cls    2017/01/22 v3.40
biblatex.sty    2016/12/05 v3.7
which are the most up to date packages in my debian 9.3 system. As soon as I'm in reach of my "big machine", I will try it with the newest packages myself.

Comment: Mhhhh, the issues I linked should have been resolved in v3.40 of `beamer`. But your problem is definitely gone with `beamer` 3.50, `biblatex` 3.11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is due to a bug in `beamer` which is fixed
in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/6dc69b711304b4b578fa51622a186abff4a5ab53#diff-15177487b51275c13573a59c399e24e6.

Where possible, you should [update your TeX
distribution](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) to install the
current release. If this is not possible, for example if you want to
change only this one package or where you do not have the privileges
to update the entire distribution, you will need to [install the
package locally](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137).  This option should be considered a last resort, since for more complex packages there may be package dependencies that will make local installation more complicated and error-prone.